# In PUG/JADE, how to avoid ambiguity between a variable name and a html tag?

Tags: javascript, html, pug, frontend

I have a code like this in pug:

```
var index=0
if user
    each prog in user["progress"]
      if prog.coursename === coursename
        index=blabla
```

However, it seems that the variable "index" was treated as a tag instead of a variable and thus caused errors.
So is there any way to avoid this ambiguity?

Comment: What are you trying to do in the line that says "index=blabla"?  Increment the value of index, or output some text?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With pug any time you start a line with a character/string you will output a tag of that type.  As you might have seen, `.` and `#` have special meanings for class and id (respectively) and using those at the start of your line creates a plain old `div`.

You can escape a line to only be [code](https://pugjs.org/language/code.html) with a dash at the start of your line like this:

```
- index = "blabla"
```

Note that the `-` operator tells pug only to evaluate the code and not to output anything.  If you do want that code to output something, you need to use `=` or `!=` at the start of the line.